# Convertir lista de tuplas a lista de str

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Necesito crear una función que me convierta una lista de tuplas como la siguiente: `lista = [(5, 8), (8, 36), (5, 56), (4, 2)]` en una lista donde todos sus elementos se hayan convertido en str.

El resultado que debería arrojar la función creada con este ejemplo debería ser:

```
res = ['(5, 8)', '(8, 36)', '(5, 56)', '(4, 2)']
```

Gracias compañer@s!!

Answer (score 2):

Sólo tienes que convertir cada tupla a str

```
res = [str(x) for x in lista]
```

Comment: Otra vía Python: res = list(map(str,lista))